# list.dataGroup.getElementAt() not returning all the elements

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, list, flex4, itemrenderer

I'm trying to cycle through my list itemRenderers to change the data of a particular item. The code runs well until the for index becomes 7 (which is the maximum number of visible elements on my list). When the index is 7 or more, the getElementAt() function returns null. What could possibly be the problem?

```
var itemRenderer:ItemRenderer;
var numItems:int = list.dataGroup.numElements;
trace(numElements) // outputs 14
for(var i:int = 0; i < numItems; i++){
        itemRenderer = list.dataGroup.getElementAt(i) as ItemRenderer;
        if (itemRenderer.data.name == "bar") {
                itemRenderer.data.option = "foo";
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the data of a particular item, why not change it from the data you gave to the `dataProvider`?  Changing it directly in the item renderer is ludicrous.

And for future reference, the reason why that fails is because of something called virtualization.  Essentially, not all item renderers are created, only the ones visible.

Comment: Yeah, I'm being dumb again. The dataProvider solution is the best in this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Spark List uses virtual layout by default (`useVirtualLayout = true`). It allows to reuse item renderers and increase performance and decrease resources usage. In your case you can set `useVirtualLayout=false` for your List.

But it is very possible you do something wrong if you need to list List's item renderers from outside. Try to solve your problem some other way and remain using virtual layout.

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried that and the invalidade{something} methods but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the RendererExistenceEvent which is fired when the ItemRenderer of the DataGroup when it receives data and is rendered.  Listen for the event rendererAdd on the DataGroup.

```
<s:DataGroup id="dataGroupList" dataProvider="{_listData}" 
width="100%" height="100%"
rendererAdd="list_rendererAddHandler(event)"/>
```

For more information, check out the help document for [RendererExistenceEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/RendererExistenceEvent.html).

Though some say it's not best practices for accessing and changing data in the ItemRenderer directly, there may be other use cases where you need to just that.  For instance, if you want to toggle the selected or enabled properties of the list based on some user interaction or state change.   Best practices only apply on the simplest use cases, other use cases require you to use these events or modify the control itself.